# a doubt on Zorn's Lemma in Dummit's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

I have a doubt in Dummit's Abstract Algebra on page909 :"It is a nontrivial result that Zorn 's Lemma is independent of the usual (Zermel£r Fraenkel) axioms of set theory1 in the sense that **if the axioms of set theory are consistent**, then so are these axioms together with Zorn's Lemma; and **if the axioms of set theory are consistent**, then so are these axioms together with the negation of Zorn's Lemma."

It's clear that the two **bold** sentences above are the same. Is there anything omitted in the first or the second one?

Comment: Ok, I realize the statements now. Thanks.

Comment: Did Dummit put the clauses in boldface, or was that you?

Comment: It is me. I just do it to emphasize where my doubt is.

Answer (score 4):

But the **bold** "sentences" are just clauses: when coupled with the rest of the context they are saying different things.

> $(1)$ If the axioms of set theory are consistent, then these axioms together with Zorn's lemma are consistent
>
> $(2)$ If the axioms of set theory are consistent, then these axioms together with **the negation** of Zorn's lemma are consistent

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are saying quite different things. There is no typo, and Dummit/Foote were not wasting their breath when they mentioned both $(1)$ and $(2)$ as there is no obvious implication between the statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do not understand it just now and it is done now.

Comment: @DianWei I'm not sure what you mean. Would you like me to try to explain what $(1)$, $(2)$ mean in more detail? Because frankly that is quite difficult and is worth a separate question, if it hasn't already been asked before. My axiomatic set theory / model theory is way too weak to give you a good treatment of the subject

Comment: By your answer, I think the two sentences (1) and (2) emphasize the word "independent". Is my thinking right?

Comment: @DianWei I don’t mention independence but I’m pretty sure that’s what it means. It is true that Zorn’s lemma is independent of ZF